# django /admin not found

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I try to setup **Nginx+Gunicorn** and when I go by my URL the **Nginx** redirects request to my app and handles it by itsels for static resource (`static` folder). Below my Nginx domain config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name asknow.local www.asknow.local;

        root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /static/ {
                root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;
        }
        location = / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/asknow.sock;
        }
}
```

**Gunicorn daemon**:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ghostman
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow
ExecStart=/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/log/gunicorn.log --error-logfile /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/env/log/gunicorn-error.log --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/asknow.sock asknow.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem that I need to **Nginx** handles request by itself for `static` only (`www.asknow.local/static`) but it tries to handle other URLs too. So when I go to `www.asknow.local/admin` now **Nginx** tries to find a resource by path (`my_project/admin`). But if I go to `www.asknow.local` Nginx proxies a request to the Gunicorn. Gunicorn error log is empty, so it fails on Nginx side.

**Nginx log**

```
2017/11/01 04:27:22 [error] 13451#13451: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/img/search.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: asknow.local, request: "GET /static/img/search.svg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.asknow.local"
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is using `=`, that is use for absolute locations. You don't want that (only for favicon.ico) you want that

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name asknow.local www.asknow.local;

        root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ghostman/Projects/asknow/asknow/asknow.sock;
        }
}
```